# Lists to Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have lists like this

```
a = ['CROXE-1478','CROXE-9087','CROXE-8744']
b = ['ENGINEER_NAME','DESCRIPTION']
c = ['John','Mark','Rock']
d = ['M5 Cloud decrease even if answer is OK!','Make  auto-answer not working.','M5  6200 raised in case of suiteId modified']
```

I want to create a dictionary like this

```
dict1 = {'CROXE-1478':{'ENGINEER_NAME':'John','DESCRIPTION':'M5 Cloud decrease even if answer is OK!'},'CROXE-9087':{'ENGINEER_NAME':'Mark','DESCRIPTION':'Make  auto-answer not working.'},'CROXE-8744':{'ENGINEER_NAME':'Rock','DESCRIPTION':'M5  6200 raised in case of suiteId modified'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
a=['CROXE-1478','CROXE-9087','CROXE-8744']
b = ['ENGINEER_NAME','DESCRIPTION']
c = ['John','Mark','Rock']
d = ['M5 Cloud decrease even if answer is OK!','Make  auto-answer not working.','M5  6200 raised in case of suiteId modified']

mainDict = {a[0]:None,a[1]:None,a[2]:None}

for i in range(0,3):
    subDict = {b[0]:c[i],b[1]:d[i]}
    mainDict[a[i]] = subDict

print(mainDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code if your a,c and d has same length

```
a = ['CROXE-1478', 'CROXE-9087', 'CROXE-8744']
b = ['ENGINEER_NAME', 'DESCRIPTION']
c = ['John', 'Mark', 'Rock']
d = ['M5 Cloud decrease even if answer is OK!', 'Make  auto-answer not working.',
     'M5  6200 raised in case of suiteId modified']

main_dict = {}
for i in range(len(a)):
    dic1 = {}
    dic1[b[0]] = c[i]
    dic1[b[1]] = d[i]
    main_dict[a[i]] = dic1
print main_dict
```

Output-

```
{'CROXE-1478': {'ENGINEER_NAME': 'John', 'DESCRIPTION': 'M5 Cloud decrease even if answer is OK!'}, 'CROXE-8744': {'ENGINEER_NAME': 'Rock', 'DESCRIPTION': 'M5  6200 raised in case of suiteId modified'}, 'CROXE-9087': {'ENGINEER_NAME': 'Mark', 'DESCRIPTION': 'Make  auto-answer not working.'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
dict1 = {code: {b[0]: name, b[1]: text} for code, name, text in zip(a, c, d)}
```

Output:

```
{'CROXE-1478': {'ENGINEER_NAME': 'John', 'DESCRIPTION': 'M5 Cloud decrease even if answer is OK!'}, 'CROXE-9087': {'ENGINEER_NAME': 'Mark', 'DESCRIPTION': 'Make  auto-answer not working.'}, 'CROXE-8744': {'ENGINEER_NAME': 'Rock', 'DESCRIPTION': 'M5  6200 raised in case of suiteId modified'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
models = ['CROXE-1478','CROXE-9087','CROXE-8744']
headings = ['ENGINEER_NAME','DESCRIPTION']
engineers = ['John','Mark','Rock']
notes = ['M5 Cloud decrease even if answer is OK!',
     'Make  auto-answer not working.',
     'M5  6200 raised in case of suiteId modified']


result = {}

for model,engineer,note in zip(models,engineers,notes):

      designation,description = headings[:]

      result[model] = {designation:engineer, description:note }


print(result)
```

---

**Result**

```
{'CROXE-1478': {'ENGINEER_NAME': 'John', 
                'DESCRIPTION': 'M5 Cloud decrease even if answer is OK!'},
 'CROXE-9087': {'ENGINEER_NAME': 'Mark', 
                'DESCRIPTION': 'Make  auto-answer not working.'}, 
 'CROXE-8744': {'ENGINEER_NAME': 'Rock', 
                'DESCRIPTION': 'M5  6200 raised in case of suiteId modified'}
}
```

**Note On zip function**

> zip will take first element from the two list and return a tuple,
>   after that it goes for the second elements from both f the lists

```
names = ['linus','richard']
ages = [47,60]

for item in zip(names,ages):

  print(item)
```